# How can i migrate all the projects in an ADO org to ADO org?

Tags: azure-devops

We have a scenario where we need to migrate more than a 100 projects that are in one ADO organization to another ADO organization.

Is there way how to do perform this migration org to org?

We have tried using the Azure migration devops tool by installing it in DEV test lab in A tenant and installed the tool.
Started with workitem migration but couldn't due to the errors.
So is there a way out to directly migrate org to org in two different ADO's?

Comment: hi divya, what's the latest status of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to migrate projects from one Azure DevOps organization to another. However, there are a few ways to accomplish this:

1. Use the Azure DevOps Migration Tools.
2. Use a third-party tool, such as OpsHub Integration Manager.
3. Manually export and import the data using the Azure DevOps REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no supported method to move an organization directly to another inside azure devops, and you could follow this user voice ticket for the upcoming feature. [make it possible to move a Team Project between Team Project Collections](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te-1/365365)